# How to Create Arrays/Objects whose dimensions are defined in another array (C#)

Tags: arrays, dynamic

Given: `int[] dimensions = new int[]{3,4,6};` is there any way to create another object as follows: `object myObj = new object[dimensions]`?

Comment: What is the desired type of the new object? `object [,,]` or `object[][][]`?

Comment: the new object should be object[,,]

Answer (score 0):

The new object can be created as follows.

```
object[,,] myObj = new object[dimensions[1],dimensions[2],dimensions[3]];
```

However, this approach will not work if the number of dimension changes.